# Добавить и удалить класс css .active

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как при нажатии или вводе текста в форму поиска, добавить `css` класс `.active` к `#container`, а потом при клике на любое место, вне поля поиска, удалить css класс `.active` ?

```js
$("#search").click(function() {
  $('#container').addClass('active');
});


$("#bloc_index").click(function() {
  $("#container").removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
#bloc_index {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  color: #555;
  font: 18px Arial, Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #777;
  text-align: center;
}
#form {
  background-color: #444;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 8px 0px;
}
.active {
  background-color: #999;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.searchInput {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font: bold 17px Arial, Helvetica;
  color: #777;
  margin-left: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 330px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  color: #a6a6a6;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px gray;
}
.searchInput:focus {
  border-color: #6699cc;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #333;
  color: #333;
}
#sumbit {
  border: 1px solid #00748f;
  height: 40px;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: bold 15px Arial, Helvetica;
  color: #fafafa;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #0483a0;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#31b2c3), to(#0483a0));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #31b2c3, #0483a0);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #31b2c3, #0483a0);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #31b2c3, #0483a0);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #31b2c3, #0483a0);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #31b2c3, #0483a0);
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 0 1px 0 #555;
}
#futer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  color: #555;
  font: 18px Arial, Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #777;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <form id="form" action="" method="post">
    <input class="searchInput" type="text" id="search" name="search" autocomplete='off' />
    <input type="submit" value="Найти" id="sumbit" name="sub" />
  </form>

</div>

<div id="bloc_index">

  <div id="container">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>Здесь много текста, фото и так далее...
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>

  <div id="futer"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно, например, вот так

```
var $search = $('тут селектор поля для поиска');
$search.on('click', function () {
    $("#container").addClass('active');
});

$search.on('blur', function () {
    $("#container").removeClass('active');
});
```

`blur` срабатывает, когда элемент потерял фокус ( в данном случае кликнули не по поиску )